# only allow one "Yes" in a column, but allow several "no"

Tags: excel

I have a work sheet with several columns, one column has the position titles of my reports this is chosen from a drop down list.

What I want to do is read that column input, and if the value is "chief" then input into another column the value "YES". Then in this column only one "yes" will be allowed. This means there can only be one chief per project but I can have several engineers for example.

How can I do this?

Here is a sample data
[data sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qIlN.png)

Comment: What have you tried? Should be relatively simple with `COUNTIFS()`?

Comment: You also might be able to manage this with a dependent drop down list https://www.excel-university.com/create-depdendent-drop-downs-conditional-data-validation/

Comment: Maybe include a sample layout of your data?